# MD5 Error while installing package libc6:i386 on Crostini

Tags: debian, lib, deb, crostini

I'm trying to install the libc6:i386 library (for a multitude of reasons) on my Chromebook, but when I try to install, I get the following error(s):

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.31-13+deb11u6_i386.deb (--unpack):
 cannot compute MD5 hash for file '/usr/share/doc/libc6/NEWS.gz': failed to read (Input/output error)
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.31-13+deb11u6_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

This had all happened when at first I ran the command:

`sudo apt-get install libc6:i386`

But I got said error, so I used `sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 -f` in hopes that it might work that way, but it didn't. Afterward, I had ran it while in root, still to no avail. After that, I went to [here](https://pkgs.org/download/libc6-i386) to get the DEB file and run it graphically, but I got the same error except dumbed down to:

`Error while installing package: cannot compute MD5 hash for file '/usr/share/doc/libc6/NEWS.gz'`